# I can see the candle color changes with this code, but I want to use it for these heiken ashi candles

Tags: pine-script

I can see the candle color changes with this code, but I want to use it for these heiken ashi candles. thanks

```
    open[1] > close[1] and close > open 
    open[1] < close[1] and close < open
```

Comment: That code will not change the candle colors. What you have is a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `barcolor()` function to change the candlestick's colors. Then select heiken ashi candlestick type and you are good to go, you don't need any specific code for heiken ashi.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

c_1 = open[1] > close[1] and close > open ? color.white : na
c_2 = open[1] < close[1] and close < open ? color.blue : na
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I explained it wrong, I get a list with this code, but it lists me normal candlestick charts instead of heiken ashi, I want to see heiken ashi

```
indicator(title="sade tarama", overlay=true)
sart = open[1] > close[1] and close > open 
sartt = open[1] < close[1] and close < open

customFunc() => (sart or sartt)

sure = '60'

s1 = request.security('BTCUSDTPERP   ', sure, customFunc())
s2 = request.security('ETHUSDTPERP   ', sure, customFunc())
s3 = request.security('BNBUSDTPERP   ', sure, customFunc())
s4 = request.security('ADAUSDTPERP   ', sure, customFunc())

src_label = 'Taramalar\n--------------\n'
src_label :=  s1 ? src_label + '01- BTC   \n' : src_label      
src_label :=  s2 ? src_label + '02- ETH   \n' : src_label   
src_label :=  s3 ? src_label + '03- BNB   \n' : src_label   

aaa = label.new(time+10, close, src_label, color=color.green, 
textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_left, textalign=text.align_left, 
xloc=xloc.bar_time)
label.delete(aaa[1])
```